# GCM android Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=DISPLAY.MESSAGE flg=0x10 (has extras)

Tags: java, android

I have troubles when I start the app and register device in Gcm

Any idea how to fix it?

The rest is working fine, I receive the notification and correctly.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.v("MESSAGE", intent.getExtras().getString("message") );
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            aController.acquireWakeLock(getApplicationContext());       
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Releasing wake lock
            aController.releaseWakeLock();
        }
    };
```

Error

```
01-10 20:11:09.945: W/dalvikvm(20161): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c5a1f8)
01-10 20:11:09.945: E/AndroidRuntime(20161): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 20:11:09.945: E/AndroidRuntime(20161): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=example.gcm.testing.DISPLAY_MESSAGE flg=0x10 (has extras) } in example.gcm.testing.MainActivity$1@41a0a2d8
01-10 20:11:09.945: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:737)
01-10 20:11:09.945: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-10 20:11:09.945: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-10 20:11:09.945: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 20:11:09.945: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
01-10 20:11:09.945: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 20:11:09.945: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 20:11:09.945: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
01-10 20:11:09.945: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
01-10 20:11:09.945: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 20:11:09.945: E/AndroidRuntime(20161): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 20:11:09.945: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at example.gcm.testing.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:146)
01-10 20:11:09.945: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
```

Answer (score 1):

your code for extra is returning null,

```
String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
```

use try catch, and make sure you have extra to be received from there!

Comment: try {
    //Log.v("MESSAGE", intent.getExtras().getString("message") );
    String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
    // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
    aController.acquireWakeLock(context);  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Releasing wake lock
    aController.releaseWakeLock();
          // DB operation
        } catch (Exception e){
          //throw new RuntimeException(e);
         Log.v("YEAH", e.getMessage());
        }

Comment: But I have not any message in the log

Comment: is your mobile at sleep or not the time message arrives?

Comment: My problem is when I just installed app (first time), and register in the GCM, I get this error, after that works like a charm, I don't understand why. After this crash receive meesage and generate notification correctly.

Comment: There might be no TAG as "message" you are using. What does GCM returns the first time it registers the device? did you read the documentation?

Comment: you better double click on this line 'at example.gcm.testing.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:146)' number 146 and see where does it takes you, that will be the cause of your error.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I`m new in java, I don't know how to check all the Extras I get from the Intent, and convert them to string and log them to check, is there a way to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Log.v("MESSAGE", intent.getExtras().getString("price"));
String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("price");
```